# MEAN App on server crashes

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, express, nginx, mean-stack

I try to run a MEAN App on an Nginx server, but it always crashes after:

```
// port is 8080
app.listen(port, (data) => {
  console.log('Listening on port ' + port + ' in ' + process.env.NODE_ENV + ' mode');
});
```

My firewall's status is

```
Status: active
To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
OpenSSH                    ALLOW       Anywhere  
Nginx Full                 ALLOW       Anywhere   
8080                       ALLOW       Anywhere  
OpenSSH (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6) 
Nginx Full (v6)            ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
8080 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

**Error**

```
listen EADDRINUSE :::8080
```

I've used [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-node-js-application-for-production-on-ubuntu-16-04) to setup the server.

Seems like 8080 is already in use, but how can I find out what it's used for and fix it?

Comment: @skirtle updated

Comment: You can try to use `netstat` to figure out what is on that port, or just try connecting to port 8080 (e.g. using `curl`) to see if anything responds.

Comment: Seems like either your app is already running and you are trying to launch another instance or something else is listening on that port already. This is a port binding issue

Comment: @TarunLalwani Yeah seems like it's already running, how can I terminate this process?

Comment: `ps aux | grep node`, get the id and using `kill -9 <id>` or use `pkill node`

Comment: I mean.. changing the port is just a temporary fix, you just gonna change the port the next time it fails to close too?

Comment: @TarunLalwani I tired to, but every time I kill it's running again with another PID

Comment: That means its running through a service. Which process is using 8080?

Comment: @TarunLalwani Node, but I need my express app to listen to it

Comment: See if there is some service or some process launching it again and again

Comment: @TarunLalwani How do I do?

Comment: @TarunLalwani I've used [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-node-js-application-for-production-on-ubuntu-16-04)

Comment: What is the output of `ps aux | grep pm2`

Comment: @TarunLalwani
`webmast+  2243  0.0  0.1  12916   936 pts/2    S+   20:06   0:00 grep --color=auto pm2`

`root     11751  0.0  5.5 921572 27680 ?        Ssl  Oct21   1:31 PM2 v2.7.2: God Daemon (/root/.pm2)`

`webmast+ 11925  0.0  3.3 884932 16648 ?        Ssl  Oct21   0:07 PM2 v2.7.2: God Daemon (/home/webmaster/.pm2`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157406/discussion-between-tarun-lalwani-and-michael-cool).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you mentioned you followed the tutorial

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-node-js-application-for-production-on-ubuntu-16-04

This indicates you ran PM2 which is relaunching node even when you kill it. So you need to stop PM2

```
sudo pkill PM2
```

Then you will be able to launch your node program normally

Answer (score -1):

To try getting what process is listening to a port enter:

```
sudo netstat -tulpn | grep :8080
```

That should hopefully give you what is using that port.

To then kill a process by PID, just use

```
sudo kill pid
```

from https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/what-process-has-open-linux-port/

An alternative way is to just use `sudo fuser -k 8080/tcp` to kill processes on port 8080 on TCP directly.

Comment: It did and I've found it's PID. How can I terminate it?

Comment: Ok just changed the port and now it works, thanks :)

Comment: Included a way to kill a process by PID now. It appears I was beat to it though by @TarunLalwani though.

Comment: I tired to, but every time I kill it's running again with another PID

Comment: There, added on a method with fuser, just if it is killing another process for those that might find this on Google.